# How to get the header values for an ASCII raster if the input raster is QgsRasterLayer type?

Tags: pyqgis, convert, ascii

I'm trying to develop a QGIS plugin for converting the input raster to QgsRasterLayer type and, however, I don't know how to get all the header information to write it in the output raster.

This is an example of the beginning of the input raster:

```
ncols        1914
nrows        1316
xllcorner    511542.500000000000
yllcorner    4660867.500000000000
cellsize     5.000000000000
NODATA_value  -999
-999.0 -999 -999 -999 -999...
```

I know how to get cols, rows and nodatavalue but I need to know how to get xllcorner, yllcorner and cellsize too.

This is the code that I wrote for that:

```
def inversion(self):

    lyr=self.inRaster

    cols = lyr.width()
    rows = lyr.height()
    dpr = lyr.dataProvider()
    bl = dpr.block(1, dpr.extent(), cols, rows)
    nodatavalue=bl.noDataValue()

    elevation = []
    for i in range(rows):
        elevationline = []
        for j in range(cols):
            elevationline.append(bl.value(i, j))
        elevation.append(elevationline)

    headerdem={'ncols':cols,'nrows':rows,'NODATA_value':nodatavalue}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out following code at Python Console of QGIS for printing values you need:

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

xsize = lyr.rasterUnitsPerPixelX() #x cell size
ysize = lyr.rasterUnitsPerPixelY() #y cell size

print(xsize, ysize)

extent = lyr.extent()

xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = extent.toRectF().getCoords()

xllcorner = xmin
yllcorner = ymax
```

Result, with my particular raster, was:

```
73.98872322814125 73.9887232281416
354971.3488602247 4473428.402390091
```

So, you can adapt above code for your plugin.

Comment: Thank you. I adapted the code for my plugin and now I have xllcorner, yllcorner and cellsize. I only needed to change yllcorner=ymin

Comment: You're welcome.  If you think your qüestion was answered please mark as accepted.